# How to change and add new columns from app in DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I want to add new columns from app instead of rows. I'm using `Windows Forms` and `DataGridView` with `DataTable` as data source. How can I do it?

I tried to change `RowHeaderSelect` to `ColumnHeaderSelect`, but it is another thing, it doesn`t affect to my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting this.dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true and then whenever you add a new column to a dataTable, it should automatically add a new column in grid.

Here's a sample working code

```
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace testApp
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
            var dt = new DataTable();
            this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Id"));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Name"));
        }
    }
}
```

The above example is a basic stuff to get you started. You can do everything at run-time what you think you're able to do with form designer. Just go through the form's designer.cs file and see the logic behind the magic of VS form designer

Comment: Thanks for advice! But I mean, that I need to add new columns from my compiled app. For default, I can add new rows and edit row, but I want to add and edit column. Is it impossible?

Comment: If you don't have the source code, you can't do it this way. But since you've mentioned c#, winforms and datagrid, I assume you are having access to the code. So yes you can incorporate logic to do it at run-time in a compiled app. For instance you can create a button and on its clicked event, you can add a new column using the code example above. You can take user input for naming ETC for the new column as well. You're effectively building a grid designer this way which is feasible but requires more work for obvious reasons.

Comment: You`re correct! I can just create button. Thanks for all!

Comment: Your welcome. Btw You can accept the answer if it has helped you solve your query